# python: filter a list of strings based on a string name

Tags: python, list

I have a lists of strings that look like this:

```
li1 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3', '3 packages installed', '', 'bla']

l12 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', '2 packages installed', 'bla', 'bla']
```

I want to filter out from the lists the strings 'x packages installed' and those that follow to have:

```
out1 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3']


out2 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4']
```

How can I do that using list comprehension? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), which takes items from the list until the given condition is not passed:

```
from itertools import takewhile

l12 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', '2 packages installed', 'bla', 'bla']
li1 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3', '3 packages installed', '', 'bla']



r12 = takewhile(lambda x: "packages installed" not in x, l12)
ri1 = takewhile(lambda x: "packages installed" not in x, li1)
print(list(r12))
# ['pin 2.3', 'vlo 5.4']

print(list(ri1))
# ['pin 2.3', 'vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3']
```

Comment: May be overkill for this question.

Comment: @MoonCheesez I would think so too. But this stops once the condition fails as opposed to a list comprehension

Comment: what's the text for a single package installed? is it `1 package installed`? could cause a miss in that case. just really something for OP to consider. this answer is spot on.

Comment: If this data is large enough I would recommend you to use Machine Learning Linear Regression and find duplicates. Based on Training.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple:

```
li1 = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3', '3 packages installed', '', 'bla']

out1 = []
for x in li1:
    if "packages installed" in x:
        break
    out1.append(x)

print(out1)
# ['pin 2.3', 'vlo 5.4', 'lu 1.3']
```

Edit: It seems like I'm a little bit late.

Answer (score -1):

[`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) works well if you want a new list. To modify the original list *in-place* you could do:

```
>>> L = ['pin 2.3','vlo 5.4', '2 packages installed', 'bla-bla']
>>> for i, v in enumerate(L):
...     if "packages installed" in v:
...         del L[i:]
...         break
... 
>>> L
['pin 2.3', 'vlo 5.4']
```